# Multiple Textures in OpenGL Tao Framework

Tags: c#, opengl, tao-framework

I am working in OpenGL, Tao Framework. I have done all the programming, but I can't insert more than one texture. This is my code. What should I insert in order to get another image into the array? This is how i call 3 textures but the 3th and other textures are allway owerwriten.

> ```
>         Gl.glClearDepth(1.0);
>         Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
>         Gl.glFrontFace(Gl.GL_CW);         
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
>         Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);
>
>         Gl.glDepthFunc(Gl.GL_LEQUAL);                             
>         Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, Gl.GL_NICEST);   
>
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
>
>         texture = new uint[5];
>
>         Bitmap image = new Bitmap("1.jpg");
>         image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
>         System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapdata;
>         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
>
>         bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
>             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
>
>
>         Gl.glGenTextures(1, texture);
>         Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
>         Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
>             0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>
>         Gl.glViewport(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height);
>         Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
>         Gl.glLoadIdentity();
>         Glu.gluPerspective(60, ((float)Size.Width / (float)Size.Height), 0.1, 1000);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
>
>         image = new Bitmap("2.jpg");
>         image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
>         rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
>
>         bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
>             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
>
>
>         Gl.glGenTextures(1, texture);
>         Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
>         Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
>             0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>
>         Gl.glViewport(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height);
>         Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
>         Gl.glLoadIdentity();
>         Glu.gluPerspective(60, ((float)Size.Width / (float)Size.Height), 0.1, 1000);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
>
>         image = new Bitmap("3.jpg");
>         image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
>
>         rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
>
>         bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
>             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
>
>
>         Gl.glGenTextures(1, texture);
>         Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
>         Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
>             0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>         Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);     // Linear Filtering
>
>         Gl.glViewport(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height);
>         Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
>         Gl.glLoadIdentity();
>         Glu.gluPerspective(60, ((float)Size.Width / (float)Size.Height), 0.1, 1000);
>         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean? do you mean how to create/load a second texture or how to do multi texturing?

Comment: i want to add multiple textures into an array.  Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]); this is how i load the first one and want to load more.

Comment: You want to bind multiple textures using `glBindTexture()` ?

Comment: yes, i have to put them into an array. so far i managed to put in 2 textures if there are morre they will overite all that are on index 1 and more

Comment: Well just call `glBindTexture()` multiple times, you can't call `glBindTexture()` once containing an array of texture handles.

Comment: i updated my current code. this is how i do it. i call glBindTextur( multiple times and it works. But the 3th overides the 2nd and all below.

Comment: Yes each time you call `glBindTexture()` it will override all the old `glBindTexture()` calls. But please try to explain what you overall are trying to achieve, and then I might be able to help.

Comment: i have to create a cube, and texture each side whit another txture.I only have an array called texture to fill whit textures.             Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]); this is how i have to call the texture

Comment: I'm confused about your question, I can see that you've already found a solution, though the solution only shows how to create multiple textures, and not how to use them, as that was what I thought the question what about.

Comment: i had a problem creating them, not using. thou i was not that shure where the problem is. anyway i couldnt done it whitout you thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is how i done it and now it works. Thak you Vallentin for your help. Can i somehow give u points ? The glBindTexture() idea gave me an idea it was glGenTextures , that kinda holds the instances of the textures.

```
private void initGL()
    {

        Gl.glClearDepth(1.0);
        Gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // Hidden surface removal
        Gl.glFrontFace(Gl.GL_CW);           // clock-wise polygons face out
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);

        Gl.glDepthFunc(Gl.GL_LEQUAL);                               // type of depth testing
        Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, Gl.GL_NICEST); // nice perspective calculations

        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        texture = new uint[6];

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap("1.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapdata;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glGenTextures(5, texture);
        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[5]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering

         image = new Bitmap("2.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

         rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);

        image = new Bitmap("3.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);

        image = new Bitmap("4.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);

        image = new Bitmap("5.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);

        image = new Bitmap("6.jpg");
        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

        rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

        bitmapdata = image.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // storage for texture for one picture

        Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
        Gl.glTexImage2D(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, (int)Gl.GL_RGB8, image.Width, image.Height,
            0, Gl.GL_BGR_EXT, Gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapdata.Scan0);
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);       // Linear Filtering
        Gl.glTexParameteri(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, Gl.GL_LINEAR);

        Gl.glViewport(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height);
        Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
        Gl.glLoadIdentity();

        Glu.gluPerspective(60, ((float)Size.Width / (float)Size.Height), 0.1, 1000);

    }
```